# Эмуляция действий пользователя

Tags: android

Требуется создать приложение, управляющее пользовательским интерфейсом ос андроид:

- эмуляция нажатия по системным клавишам
- открытие приложений
- произведение действий в них, в основном эмуляция кликов.

Главное — чтобы можно было реализовать проверку отображаемой информации на экране.

Первым пришедшим на ум стало решение автотеста, но при более детальном изучении столкнулся с тем, что все они посылают команды извне, а требуется полностью изолированное решение без задействования сторонних ОС.

Далее наткнулся на monkeyrunner и sl4a, но к сожалению уже запутался в понимании того, что надо.

Как можно реализовать эту задачу, желательно по пути наименьшего сопротивления?

Comment: Вам стоит начать с разделения потока слов на предложения, а предложений - на параграфы.  Затем сформулировать конкретный вопрос.

Comment: @VTT Прошу прощение, думаю так немного лучше.

Comment: гугль целую концепцию работы изолированных друг от друга приложений придумал и реализовал её в рамках dalvik/linux, а вам «требуется» вот так с наскока написать мега-вирус, который с пол-пинка взломает все слои изоляции? нда, хорошие вам выставили требования. как реализуете — отправьте результаты не заказчику, а в гугль. думаю, там заплатят на порядки больше.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin ,благодарю за комментарий. Если рассматривать на примере anydesk, то по сути это то что нужно, только на другом конце провода вместо пользователя который управляет устройством скрипт который эмулирует действия пользователя и соответственно без удаленки а все локально. Это очень грубый пример, прошу простить если в чем то не прав, так как еще нет обширного понимания.

Comment: в вопросе у вас — о программе, управляющей устройством, на котором запущена dalvik/linux. а в комментарии вы упоминаете программу anydesk (видимо, [эту](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.anydesk.anydeskandroid)), которая выполняет противоположную задачу: управляет устройством, на котором запущена ms/windows или apple/macos. вы как-то определитесь, **чем** вам надо управлять.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin , также данное приложение anydesk , предоставляет возможность управление андроид устройством андроид устройства,  то есть предоставляет возможность взаимодействовать с пользовательским интерфейсом андроида. И да , скорее не управлять а взаимодействовать с пользовательским интерфейсом андроид и установленных приложений.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin к дополнению  [это]https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n6ftrryV-7s) видео о том как данное удаленное  управление происходит в другой подобной программе TeamViwer.